# iOS get default UISearchBar icon to set in UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uisearchbar

Iam trying to get the default UISearchBar icon (Magnifying glass) to set in another UIButton.

PS: I don't want to use a png downloaded from somewhere i want to use the default one.

func to add the button with a custom image just to show some example:

```
func addRightNavigationButton(){
    let buttonBack: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    buttonBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 33)
    buttonBack.setImage(UIImage(named:"search.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonBack.addTarget(self, action: "barButtonItemClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    var rightBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonBack)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(rightBarButtonItem, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Objective-C:**

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(searchButtonItemClicked:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:searchItem animated:FALSE];
```

**In Swift 1.2:**

```
let searchItem : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: "searchButtonItemClicked:")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchItem;
```

Comment: Thank you @Nishant i tried with swift but xcode says can't find "UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch", can you provide a snippet in swift

Comment: Sure. I have updated my answer with swift code. Please check.

Comment: Thank you once again in the moment just before you answer i realize how to do it but thanks. sorry for the noob question i'am an Android guy starting in iOS so sometimes it's hard to switch from Android structure to iOS

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
let searchBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.search, target: self, action: #selector(self.searchFunction))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this UIImage Extension to get System icons anywhere in your app.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    public convenience init?(_ systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem) {

        guard let sysImage = UIImage.imageFrom(systemItem: systemItem)?.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(cgImage: sysImage)
    }

    private class func imageFrom(systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem) -> UIImage? {

        let sysBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: nil, action: nil)

        //MARK:- Adding barButton into tool bar and rendering it.
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.setItems([sysBarButtonItem], animated: false)
        toolBar.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)

        if  let buttonView = sysBarButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView{
            for subView in buttonView.subviews {
                if subView is UIButton {
                    let button = subView as! UIButton
                    let image = button.imageView!.image!
                    return image
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is an example of how do we use it:

```
 let button = UIButton() ;
 let systemImage = UIImage(systemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.search) ;
 button.setImage(systemImage, for: .normal)
```